# How to create vue project with vite and yarn

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, vuejs3, vite

I watch Vue series on Udemy. He write yarn add vue@3.0.7 and yarn add vite@2.1.1 --developer. Also I'm writing thoose commands in a terminal but I see node_modules, package.json files src folder is missing. How to create dynamiclly in src folder? I don't want to download and setup empty project.

Comment: Did you follow official documentation? https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Answer (score 5):

Vite's [*Getting Started* docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) show how to use `yarn` to scaffold a project, including `package.json` (which will have the necessary dependencies) and the `src` directory.

Use the following command to create a directory named `my-vite-project`, and select `vue` when prompted:

```sh
yarn create vite my-vite-project
```

*Example run:*

```sh
$ yarn create vite my-vite-project
yarn create v1.16.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-vite@2.6.4" with binaries:
      - create-vite
      - cva
✔ Select a framework: › vue
✔ Select a variant: › vue

Scaffolding project in /Users/tony/src/tmp/my-vite-project...

Done. Now run:

  cd my-vite-project
  yarn
  yarn dev

✨  Done in 38.38s.
```